# Is there a javascript library for displaying RTSP on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am going to display an RTSP stream on a webpage. I figured out that currently no browsers support RTSP protocol for HTML5 video tag. However, there are some plugins such as VLC ActiveX to do the job. But, unfortunately, they are OS or platform dependent. A javascript library would be the best choice, though. Do you know any javascript library for handling RTSP streams? If there is not any, do you have any suggestion on how to start developing one?